# Possible to force the use of a specific method signature in an application?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a helper assembly that assists developers with logging information.  The specific method used for logging has two signatures:

```
LogToULS(string message)
LogToULS(string message, Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsCategory category)
```

In my application I have created a static class that contains an instance of the SPDiagnosticsCategory that I would like to be used any time the application logs something.  If the first signature is used, a generic category is assigned and it is harder to find logged information specific to this application.

My question is if it's possible to force people to use the second signature any time `LogToULS` is called from this application or does this need to be accomplished through programmer education?

Comment: any problem with just removing the first function from  your API ?

Comment: It is still in use in other projects and still has it's place, just not in this particular project.

Comment: In this case, where you have a backcompatibility issue, I'm afraid there is no any other solution then just educating...

Comment: If you cannot remove the API member, then programmer education is all you have to go on. Otherwise, you have done the best you can by providing a 'fall-back' - e.g. creating a default SPDiagnosticsCategory.

Comment: Mark this function as obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664623(v=vs.71).aspx. At least Visual Studio intellisense will help the user to identify the right one. Oh! @Bradley was fast !

Comment: Would it be possible just to call the logging overload with the old function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't remove the method from the codebase, you could mark it as deprecated, so other programmers get a compiler warning whenever they call it (and IntelliSense will warn against its usage):

```
[Obsolete("Use LogToULS(string, SPDiagnosticsCategory) instead."]
public void LogToULS(string message)
{
    // ...
}
```

As per the [`ObsoleteAttribute` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx), you can pass `true` as a second parameter to its constructor to cause a compiler error (not just a warning), but this may break existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Define the first overload as:

```
public void LogToULS(string message)
{
    LogToULS(message, genericErrorCodeHere);
}
```

Then, make **Resharper** inline this method so all existing call sites get updated. Next, delete the old, obsolete overload.